# How to introduce a Json Converter using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, json, dependency-injection, architecture

Does anyone know a good method or pattern where I can give a hierarchy of plain old model classes the capability of converting them from and to Json strings while

- Using dependency injection for the JsonConverter dependency
- Being implementation-agnostic to the JsonConverter
- Being able to give the JSON capability to a class quickly without using much code
- Using ToString() as convenience method for displaying the objects content as Json string
- Keeping with the rules of Clean Coding?

I have started with the below idea, however I found that the following problems arise:

1. When I have dozens of model classes and use them in many places I always have to pass the converter to every model class and obviously to every class that is using the model class. It's like a virus.
2. When I want to convert Json strings back to objects I cannot use the constructor with the injected dependency as it's the Json converter that creates the objects.

Code example (does not yet compile):

```
public abstract class JsonObj
{
    private readonly IJsonConverter jsonConverter;
    protected JsonObj(IJsonConverter jsonConverter) => this.jsonConverter = jsonConverter;

    public virtual string ToJson() => jsonConverter.Serialize(this);
    public static JsonObj FromJson(string json, Type type) => jsonConverter.Deserialize(json, type);
    public override string ToString() => ToJson();
}

public class OneOfManyModelObjects : JsonObj
{
    public OneOfManyModelObjects(IJsonConverter jsonConverter) : base(jsonConverter) { }
    public static OneOfManyModelObjects FromJson(string json) => FromJson(json, typeof(OneOfManyModelObjects)) as OneOfManyModelObjects;
}
```

Comment: why dont you use newtonsoft json, it is very easy to use and in most cases you will end you playing with json even without creating objects and classes

Comment: @prany Yes, I do use Newtonsoft.Json. But I want the model objects to be implementation-independent, that's why I inject a converter interface.